# php current time greater than timestamp gives false result

Tags: php, timestamp

Can't figure out why the following returns false:

```
$timestamp = '1535552942';
if (time() <= strtotime((int)$timestamp + 10))) // time() = 1535553866
```

The current time IS greater than the timestamp + 10 s!!! I've checked in logs!

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Why do you use `strtotime` here, and not just compare timestamps directly?

Comment: because I compare it to current time, there's only 1 timestamp

Comment: Well when given a timestamp `strtotime` will try to parse it as a date which may not be a good idea. What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Have you even checked the result of `strtotime` in your case? It's `false`, as the function fails to process the timestamp, expecting some definition of date instead.

Comment: Yes, it's strtotime = '1535554662'

Comment: Check [this example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f539066278e422f4e7c0ec41fd88c8fd43bc081) if you pass the result of `strtotime(time())` you'll get a timestamp corresponding to the year 5000 which is definately going to be much greater than that 10 digit timestamp you've got there.

Comment: did you check your time server ? It's certainly the problem your server are not to the good time

Comment: it shouldn't matter because the 2 strings are logged and I see the time()'s greater than the stamp but the if still passes

Comment: Can you explain how `strtotime` results in `'1535554662'` (string) in your case, and in `31009790155` (int) here at [this demo](https://3v4l.org/NMT9E)? Which PHP version is used, by the way?

Comment: @linuxoid which solution did work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the [**docs**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> **strtotime**
>
> Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

In other words, you pass something that makes sense in English into this function - and expect timestamp as a result.

Instead you pass timestamp into the function, and `strtotime` just fails to get what you want from it. For example, this [online demo](https://3v4l.org/FCcqf) shows `int(31009790155)` as result of `strtotime((int)$timestamp + 10))` - which is in the future far far away.

Perhaps you meant it to be implemented this way:

```
$timestamp = '1535552942';
if ( time() <= strtotime('+10 seconds', $timestamp) ) { ... }
```

... but actually I fail to see why you can't just add 10 (as a number) to timestamp and then compare it against `time()` directly. These are the numbers, in the end.

Comment: Nope, that fails too

Comment: Define `fails`.

Comment: it passes the if, that is the result of strtotime > time() but it must be the opposite, the time() is always > timestamp

Comment: Check [this demo](https://3v4l.org/FCcqf), debug your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official website of PHP, the definition of function `strtotime` is....

> **strtotime**
>
> Parse about any English textual datetime description into
>   a Unix timestamp

What this definition says that you can provide **Only English textual** datetime. And you are providing it an Integer whereas this `strtotime` is looking for English textual. 
When you will print return value of `strtotime` it will show your current timestamp.

```
$timestamp = 'now';
echo strtotime($timestamp);
```

But when you will try to print its return value with an integer argument, then it will nothing, as given below...

```
$timestamp = 1535552942;
echo strtotime($timestamp);
```

Because this function return timestamp on success otherwise return false.

When you will provide it English textual value and try to add one in argument, it will generate a warning...

```
$timestamp = 'now';
echo strtotime($timestamp+1);
```

> **Warning**: A non-numeric value encountered in

Because, according to the [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.other-changes.php) generates errors or warning on arithmetics with invalid strings.

> New E_WARNING and E_NOTICE errors have been introduced when invalid
>   strings are coerced using operators expecting numbers or their assignment equivalents. An E_NOTICE is emitted when the string begins with a numeric value but contains trailing
>   non-numeric characters, and an E_WARNING is emitted when the string
>   does not contain a numeric value.

Whereas above-given snippet fulfill this condition.

So, now just change your value of $timestamp to "**now**" or any other valid English textual and remove `int` from your if condition, then it will work perfectly.

```
$timestamp = "now";
if (time() <= strtotime($timestamp)){
    echo "it works";
}
```